# Connecting Ionic 2 with laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, angular, ionic2

I saw a tutorial how to connect Angular 2 as a front end with Laravel as a back end ,my question, is connecting angular 2 with laravel is same connecting ionic 2 with laravel ??

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the same. However, it might be the same approach, since ionic is based on angular. Usually this connection is done via API. You create an access point to the back-end and send the request via ionic to a route in your application. The interaction is done via API.